# SonarQube: Unable to read 7.1.1-coverage.ec to determine JaCoCo binary format

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, sonarqube, jacoco

Gradle version: 2.2.3

Sonarqube version: 6.1

Sonarqube gradle plugin version: 2.2.1

Java plugin version: 4.4.0.8066, Android plugin version: 1.1

Sonarqube gradle task:

```
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

ext {
    SONAR_HOST = "http://localhost:9000/"
}
sonarqube() {
    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    properties {
        /* SonarQube needs to be informed about your libraries and the android.jar to understand that methods like
     * onResume() is called by the Android framework. Without that information SonarQube will very likely create warnings
     * that those methods are never used and they should be removed. Same applies for libraries where parent classes
     * are required to understand how a class works and is used. */
        def libraries = project.android.sdkDirectory.getPath() + "/platforms/android-24/android.jar," +
                "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/exploded-aar/**/classes.jar"
        property "sonar.projectName", (String) android.defaultConfig.applicationId
        property "sonar.projectKey", android.defaultConfig.applicationId + android.defaultConfig.versionName
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"

        property "sonar.sources", "./src/main/"
        property "sonar.libraries", libraries
        property "sonar.binaries", "/intermediates/classes/debug"
        property "sonar.java.binaries", "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug"
        property "sonar.java.libraries", libraries
        property "sonar.exclusions", "build/**,**/*.png,*.iml, **/*generated*, "

        property "sonar.import_unknown_files", true
        property "sonar.android.lint.report", "./build/outputs/lint-results.xml"
        property "sonar.host.url", SONAR_HOST
        property "sonar.tests", "./src/test/, ./src/androidTest/"
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", fileTree(dir: project.projectDir, includes: ['**/*.exec'])
        property "sonar.java.test.binaries", "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug"
        property "sonar.jacoco.itReportPath", fileTree(dir: project.projectDir, includes: ['**/*.ec'])
        property "sonar.java.test.libraries", libraries

    }
}
```

JaCoCo version: 0.7.8
JaCoCo task snippet:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion "0.7.8"
    //toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
}
// run ./gradlew clean createDebugCoverageReport jacocoTestReport

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testDebugUnitTest") {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class',
                      '**/R$*.class',
                      '**/BuildConfig.*',
                      '**/Manifest*.*',
                      'android/**/*.*',
                      '**/Lambda$*.class', //Retrolambda
                      '**/Lambda.class',
                      '**/*Lambda.class',
                      '**/*Lambda*.class',
                      '**/*Lambda*.*',
                      '**/*Builder.*',
                      '**/*_MembersInjector.class',  //Dagger2 generated code
                      '**/*_MembersInjector*.*',  //Dagger2 generated code
                      '**/*_*Factory*.*', //Dagger2 generated code
                      '**/*Component*.*', //Dagger2 generated code
                      '**/*Module*.*', //Dagger2 generated code
                      '**/*JsonObjectMapper*.*'
    ]
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: project.projectDir, includes:
            ['**/*.exec' , '**/*.ec'])
}
```

Also, I have in my build.gradle file next lines for JaCoCo:

```
testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            jacoco {
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
            }
        }
    }
```

What I'm getting in input:

```
:app:sonarqube                 
Class not found: android.support.annotation.Nullable
Class not found: android.support.annotation.StyleRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.LayoutRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.IdRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.RestrictTo
Class not found: android.support.annotation.RestrictTo$Scope
Class not found: android.support.annotation.CallSuper
Class not found: android.support.annotation.NonNull
Class not found: android.support.annotation.RequiresApi
The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
  java.rmi.Remote              
:app:sonarqube FAILED          

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:sonarqube'.
> Unable to read D:\Android\Projects\ProjectName\app\build\outputs\code-coverage\connected\Nexus 6P - 7.1.1-coverage.ec to determine JaCoCo binary format.
```

Stacktrace:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:sonarqube'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Unable to read D:\Android\Projects\ElzaAndroid\app\build\outputs\code-coverage\connected\Nexus 6P - 7.1.1-cove
rage.ec to determine JaCoCo binary format.
        at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoReportReader.isCurrentReportFormat(JacocoReportReader.java:98)
        at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoReportReader.<init>(JacocoReportReader.java:49)
        at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.AbstractAnalyzer.readExecutionData(AbstractAnalyzer.java:129)
        at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.AbstractAnalyzer.analyse(AbstractAnalyzer.java:102)
        at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JaCoCoItSensor.execute(JaCoCoItSensor.java:61)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:57)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:49)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:182)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:247)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:242)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:232)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:115)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:118)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
        at org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask.run(SonarQubeTask.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:228)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:621)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:604)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 68 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoReportReader.isCurrentReportFormat(JacocoReportReader.java:88)
        ... 104 more
```

I have tried everything that could be Googled. I've tried even downgrade versions of SonarQube gradle plugin and JaCoCo to 2.0.1 and 0.7.6.201602180812

Comment: I am experiencing this too.  Did you ever get a fix?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. As I remember, I've updated SonarQube and JaCoCo versions.

Comment: Device was the problem. I was running it on Samsung Tab 4 and it was giving same erroe. When I ran the same on Pixel2 then task ran successfully and able to see coverage percentage in sonar server.

Comment: @c0nst I am experiencing this with the latest JaCoCo version and sonarQube.

Answer (score -1):

Device was the problem. I was running it on Samsung J7,S8 and it was giving same error. When I ran the same on Pixel2 then task ran successfully and able to see coverage percentage in sonar server.

Comment: was it happening with Emulator as well?

Comment: @Ewoks Did not try on the emulator.